# iPhone 'steals' email from OSX mail

Tags: iphone, mac, email, macos

I'm having an odd problem with my Comcast emails. I have 2 comcast emails. Messages are received "theoretically" on both my mac(Mavericks) and iphone (ios 7).

On one of the emails (named: "Comcast2") sometimes emails only go to my iphone. 75% go to both the iPhone and the mac, but some get stolen by the iphone and I often miss them.

Has anyone experienced this before? and hopefully found a solution?

***What I have tried***
I have set both my mac and iphone emails to never delete emails from servers.

Comment: Have you verified that you are using IMAP and not POP for the account on you iPhone? You can see the account type above the Account bar in in Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> [your account].

Comment: I'm currently using POP, is that something I should change?

Comment: If possible, yes. IMAP leaves the messages on the server as default, so you don't need to worry about them disappearing, and has better support for multiple devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should switch to using IMAP protocol instead or POP. IMAP has better support for multiple devices, and leaves the messages on the server by default. For more info on POP vs. IMAP [here's](http://www.geek.com/mobile/geek-101-pop-vs-imap-1536343/) a good link.

Note that you shouldn't just change the protocol, since a part of your messages has been downloaded to your device and deleted from the server. If you change the protocol, you may experience data loss. Instead, create a new account with IMAP and the same logins, and move the missing emails to the new account. After this, it's safe to get rid of the POP account and start using the IMAP version. For mote info, check [this guide](http://www.macworld.com/article/1165600/how_to_convert_a_pop_email_account_to_imap.html).